# SQLite deployment fails unable to locate system.data.sqlite.dll vb.net

Tags: sqlite, vb.net-2010

Hoping that I do this corectly.

I am having the above issue. My development machine is win7 64. Im developing x86 application,(x86 set in compile options). I have downloaded sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.81.0 as my app will be on .net4. I have referenced the above dll, set it to copy local. Can confirm that its in the deployed dirrectory. Tests OK on development machine both as a debug and a fully instaled app. When I put the app on a separate win 7 64bit it wount run due to the Dll. It installs ok into ProgramFiles(x86) and runs untill the database is required. The dll is in the instaled dirrectory when instaled on the other PC. (fresh win instal).

I am using InstalShield and it is also telling me about an error ' -6248: Could not find dependent file system.data.sqlite.dll, or one of its dependencies of component' but it compiles OK.

Im stearing at the Dll in the program , in the references, the intelisence picksup the SQLite name and all the code is right. I have referenced by browse and then finding the dll.

What on earth could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: most .NET SQLite implmenetations I know of use a native DLL in addition to the .NET DLL - I suspect that you are missing the needed native DLL on the other machine...

Comment: I dont understand what is meant by native dll, the SQLite site has FAQ num 8 it states "Strictly speaking, there is no need to install System.Data.SQLite on any development machine The recommended way to use the assemblies is:
 • Download the precompiled binary package for your target framework and processor architecture (e.g. 32-bit x86, .NET Framework 2.0). 
• Extract the package to a directory named "Externals" inside your project directory.
• Add a reference to the "System.Data.SQLite" assembly from the "Externals" directory. 
Thats what I did .. and then far more trying to fixit.

Comment: For those that are in my shoes and are searching desperately , have a read of this. The authors of SQLite should be ashamed ! http://justanothersoftwareengineer.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/how-to-make-systemdatasqlitedll-work-on.html

Comment: Problem solved by following that link above

Comment: @R76 Please don't make/encourage others to make edits to make extreme over-usage of **bold emphasis** or *italics*. Edits should make a substantive improvement to the post. Over-usage of this sort of formatting increases noise and is generally frowned upon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has had so many views that I decided to answer this so as to help others.
The problem isnt a big deal once you know what it is, despite the error message that sends you almost in the wrong dirrection. The problem isnt the DLL, its one of its dependancies. Basicaly you have to install C++ distributable file on the client machine , even if you are using VB.net. I cant take credit for the find, it comes from here http://justanothersoftwareengineer.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/how-to-make-systemdatasqlitedll-work-on.html.